# erratic "delayed" CTE evaluation?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I observe a behaviour with CTEs which I did not expect (and seems inconsistent).
Not quite sure that it is correct...

Basically, through a CTE, I filter rows to avoid a particular problem, then use the result of that CTE to perform calculations that would break on the problematic rows which I thought I eliminated in my CTE...

Take a simple table with a varchar column that often has a number in it, but not always

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(ROW_ID      INTEGER NOT NULL
                    , GOOD_ROW    BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                    , SOME_VALUE  VARCHAR NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ROW_ID, GOOD_ROW, SOME_VALUE)
    VALUES(1, TRUE, '1'), (2, TRUE, '2'), (3, FALSE, 'ABC');
```

I also create a small table with just numbers to join on

```
CREATE TABLE NUMBERS(NUMBER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS(NUMBER_ID) VALUES(1), (2), (3);
```

Joining these two tables on SOME_VALUE results in an error because 'ABC' is not numeric and it appears that the JOIN is evaluated BEFORE the WHERE clause (**BAD** implications on performance here...)

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  INNER JOIN NUMBERS ON NUMBERS.NUMBER_ID = TO_NUMBER(SOME_VALUE)
  WHERE ROW_ID < 3; --> ERROR
```

So, I try to filter my first table through a CTE which only return rows for which SOME_VALUE is numeric

```
WITH ONLY_GOOD_ONES
AS (
  SELECT SOME_VALUE
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE GOOD_ROW = TRUE
)
SELECT *
  FROM ONLY_GOOD_ONES;
```

Now, I would expect to be able to use the result of this CTE with SOME_VALUE being numeric.

```
WITH ONLY_GOOD_ONES
AS (
  SELECT SOME_VALUE 
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE GOOD_ROW = TRUE
)
SELECT *
  FROM ONLY_GOOD_ONES 
  INNER JOIN NUMBERS ON NUMBERS.NUMBER_ID = TO_NUMBER(SOME_VALUE);
```

Miracle!!!

It worked!
I get my 2 expected records.
So far so good...

However, if I had defined my CTE slightly differently (WHERE clause which filters the same records)

```
WITH ONLY_GOOD_ONES
AS (
  SELECT SOME_VALUE 
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE ROW_ID < 3
)
SELECT *
  FROM ONLY_GOOD_ONES;
```

This CTE returns exactly the same thing as before

But if I try to join, it Fails!

```
WITH ONLY_GOOD_ONES
AS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE ROW_ID < 3
)
SELECT *
  FROM ONLY_GOOD_ONES 
  INNER JOIN NUMBERS ON NUMBERS.NUMBER_ID = TO_NUMBER(SOME_VALUE);
```

I get the following error...

> SQL Error [100038] [22018]: Numeric value 'ABC' is not recognized

Is there a particular explanation to this second version of the CTE behaving differently???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer is because snowflake does not follow the SQL standard, and execute SQL in the order given.

They apply transforms to data prior to filtering when there optimizer decides it wants to.

So for your table `MY_TABLE` when you do

```
SELECT some_value::NUMBER FROM my_table WHERE row_id IN (1,2);
```

You will under some cases have the as_number cast happen on all row, and explode on the `'ABC'`. Which is violating SQL rules, that WHERE are evaluated before SELECT transforms are done, but Snowflake have known this for years, and it's intentional, as it makes things run faster.

The solution is to understand you have mixed data and therefore assume the code can and will be ran out of order, and thus use the protective versions of the functions like [TRY_TO_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html)

The kicker is you can write a few nested SELECTs to avoid the problem and then put something like a window funcation around the code and the optimizer jump back into this behavour and you SQL explodes again. Thus the solution is to understand if you have mixed data, and handle it. Oh and complain it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any documentation about it somewhere?

Comment: no, but I have reported it a couple time over the last couple years, and the behavior of example code has changed over time.. pragmatically I enjoy the performance gains and value understanding the root cause we developing SQL, but really to wait for it to be fixed (which last time I brought it up, they said to me, they would not) I just wait code the runs, and knowing why it's intermittent is the key value to me.

Comment: Good to know. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're getting a different execution plan with the different queries.
Here's how the query is executed with the working query:
[image]

... and here is how it's executed with the query generating a failure. The error comes from the fact that the join filter is applied directly on the table scan before the ROW_ID < 3 filter is applied, compared to the working query.
[image]
You can see these plans under history, clicking the query id and then the 'profile' tab.

Comment: This is precisely what I think is WRONG.
The result of a query should certainly NOT depend on the execution plan.
I suspect I would call this a BUG

Comment: To prove my point, if you add many rows to that table as to make the optimiser think it would be better off filtering early, then the error disappear while the rows to retrieve have not changed.

Run this before running the query again and then it does not fail, yet all rows added are outside the scope of the query.


INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ROW_ID, GOOD_ROW, SOME_VALUE)
  SELECT 4 + SEQ4() AS ROW_ID, TRUE, '-1'
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount=>100000));


Definitely a bug!

Comment: Well, it's more like the execution plan is not dependent on your query syntax. This can just as well happen in a lot of other DBMS having some sort of query optimizer. It's not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the join filter is applied so early, maybe because of a wrong estimation. When I run the queries on my test database, they completed without any error.

To overcome the issue, you can always "Error-handling Conversion Functions":

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  INNER JOIN NUMBERS ON NUMBERS.NUMBER_ID = TRY_TO_NUMBER(SOME_VALUE)
  WHERE ROW_ID < 3;
```

More information:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#label-try-conversion-functions

Comment: What do you mean by wrong estimation? There is nothing wrong about it.

Comment: For the first query, it's reasonable to say that row_id filter should be applied last (based on syntax). But if you examine the last query of Eric, it's obvious that it should apply the ROW_ID filter before joining the tables. If these tables were big, and row_id was a selective predicate, "not applying this filter first" may cause a huge performance issue. This is why I say it's wrong.

Comment: Agreed, I have actually seen HUGE performance problems because of that.
For instance, a generic tool such as LOOKER could generate code that filter on currency at the very end. I have seen Snowflake produce all intermediate calculations against all currencies, before filtering the huge intermediate result on currency at the end

Comment: @Gokhan I know I could (I did actually...) avoid this problem by using TRY_TO_NUMBER() but this is not really what I am worried about.
I worry about the fact that two apparently equivalent SQL Queries produce a different result for no good reason...